# mysql date and time columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql have two columns in a table one is `date_added` and the other is `date_updated`, is it possible to  have it that the date when the data was entered is recorded in `date_added` and the date it was updated recoreded in `date_updated` without changing the `date_added` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to 5.6, MySQL only supported having one `TIMESTAMP` field that auto-initializes. This can be a 'created' or an 'updated' column, but not both at the same time.

For an auto-initializing 'created' column, use:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

For an auto-initializing 'updated' column, use

```
CREATE TABLE ...
date_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Unfortunately, you can't have both. If you want to have both auto-initialize, you will need to use triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
date_added TIMESTAMP, -- doesn't auto-initialize
date_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and then set up a `TRIGGER` to update the `date_added` field:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tablename_before_insert;

DELIMITER //

CREATE
DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
TRIGGER tablename_before_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON 
        tablename -- insert your table name here
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF IFNULL(NEW.date_added, 0) <= 0
    THEN
        SET NEW.date_added = NOW();
    END IF;
END;
//
```

The

```
 IF IFNULL(NEW.date_added, 0) <= 0
```

clause is there to allow you to override the `date_added` value, if you want.

Comment: O wow Amazing thanks alot I will try this And let you know the out come but yes it does seem 100% logical about what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Just use the correct column name in your queries. When doing your INSERT populate the `date_added` field. When doing your UPDATEs just update the `date_updated` field. The other won't be affected unless you explicitly do so in the query or with a trigger. But that is obviously in your control.

Comment: So what datatype would i use for each and default values, because for the date_updated column im using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and for date_added im using the same so they both change